# Curve integral of exponent of superharmonic function.

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, tag-removed

> Let $\phi$ be a real smooth superharmonic function on unit disc $D$ in $\mathbb C$; i.e. $\triangle \phi\le 0$.
>   Then there is a curve $\gamma$ from the center of $D$ to its boundary such that 
>   $$\int\limits_\gamma e^\phi<\infty.$$

The question came from my failed answer [to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43614).
I know that the answer is YES, but I do not see a direct proof.

Comment: How about using "greedy algorithm" to choose γ? That is, let γ(0)=0,dγ=−∇ϕ(γ) so that $e^ϕ$ is minimized in each infinitesimal step. Can superharmonicity of ϕ guarantee that γ will touch the boundary eventually, to begin with?

Comment: @Xianghong, this way you at least decrease $\phi$ along $\gamma$, 
but you might get a curve of infinite length (I do not see why not). 

Comment: @Anton, here is another "greedy curve" which will touch the boundary in finite time: let $|\gamma(r)|=r$ such that $\phi (\gamma(r))=$ min$_{|z|=r} \phi (z)$, where $ 0 \leq r < 1 $. But I am not sure if such $\gamma$ exists, and more importantly, if it has finite length.

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to show that(at least for those $\phi$ that you are interested in) $\int_{D} e^{\phi}dx<\infty$? If it is the case, then almost every radius could serve your purpose. As far as I know, $L^p$ integrability of $(\phi)_{+}$ always holds for some $p>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that $\varphi=-\psi$ where $\psi$ is subharmonic and not too weird (say, with isolated non-degenerate critical points; it seems like you can always add something bounded to achieve it but I haven't checked the details). Take any piece of some level curve of $\psi$ inside the disk parameterized by length $\ell$ and start the gradient accent from each point parameterized by the level $t$ of $\psi$. All but countably many of those escape to the boundary. Let $v(t)$ be the absolute value of the gradient and $S(t)$ be the "cross-section factor". Then $S(t)v(t)$ is non-decreasing (divergence of the gradient field is positive), the length element is $1/v(t)dt$ and the area element is $S(t)/v(t)d\ell dt$. Note that the total area of the disk is finite and the gradient curves cannot meet (we use the non-negativity of the divergence again here). Thus $\int S(t)/v(t)dt<+\infty$ most of the time. But then, since $Sv$ is non-decreasing, we also have $\int 1/v(t)^2dt<+\infty$ while we need just $\int e^{-t}/v(t)<+\infty$ and Cauchy-Schwartz ends the story.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple answer in a special case when $\phi$ is harmonic.

**Geometric proof:** Let $g_0$ be the (incomplete) metric on the unit disc induced from $\mathbb R^2$. Then the metric $e^\phi g_0$ is complete if and only if the integral
of $e^\phi$ over $\gamma$ is infinite for each $C^1$-curve $\gamma$ from the center 
to the boundary of the disk. Now the sectional curvature of $e^\phi g_0$ is $-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\phi}\Delta\phi$, which is zero since $\phi$ is assumed harmonic. Thus if $e^\phi g_0$ were complete, it would be isometric to the standard $\mathbb R^2$, but isometries are conformal, so we would get that the unit disk is conformal to the plane.

**Sketch of complex analysis proof:** If by a "direct proof" you mean then one that uses only complex analysis, then Huber's proof quoted in [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43614) does just that. However,
Huber's argument simplifies a lot when $\phi$ is harmonic. Indeed, harmonicity of $\phi$ allows you to find its harmonic conjugate, and since the disk is simply connected, $\phi$ becomes the real part of an analytic function $\tau$ on the disk. 
Thus $e^\phi=|e^\tau|$, and $e^\tau$ is analytic and nowhere vanishing. Now I think the simple argument in the [note](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=comahe-002:1960:34::10&id=browse&id2=browse2) "Paths of rapid growth of entire functions" by Kaplan does the job (see middle of the first page).

**Remark**. Kaplan's note is in fact an elaboration of the Huber's proof, and it gives a simple answer to your question for all superharmonic functions of the form $\phi=-\log|f|$ such that $f$ does not vanish (and this is what you seem to care about by restricting to smooth superharmonic functions). For general superharmonic functions I do not see how to do better than Huber.

Comment: Incidentally, applying the "geometric proof" to the plane (instead of the disk) we get the amusing conclusion that if $\phi$ is harmonic and non-constant, and $g_0$ is the standard metric on the plane, then $e^\phi g_0$ is not complete. This is because conformal automorphisms of the plane are affine maps, and pulling back the standard metric $g_0$ on the plane by an affine map yields the rescaling of $g_0$ by the conformal factor of the map.